# vbscript variable scope inside class default function

Tags: vbscript

I have two classes, one initialises with class_initialise, and the other using a default function. The one that uses a default function references the other directly. But I can't see values assigned to its properties. If I change them both to use class_initialise, it works. But I need to (eventually) pass parameters to the initialiser, so default function it is.

```
class cls1
    Public foo
    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        foo = "foo"
    End Sub
End Class

Class cls2
    Public Bar
    Public Default Function Init()
        Call SetBar()
        Set Init = Me
    End Function
    Private Sub SetBar()
        bar = fooclass.foo & ".bar"
    End Sub
End Class

Dim fooclass: Set fooclass = new cls1
Dim barclass: Set barclass = new cls2
```

Now

```
MsgBox fooclass.foo ' Shows "foo"
MsgBox barclass.bar ' is empty, not even ".bar"
```

I'm sure there's something appallingly simple jumping out of the screen at me, but I can't figure out what it actually is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
Dim barclass: Set barclass = new cls2
```

does not call the default method .Init(). You could use

```
Dim barclass: Set barclass = (new cls2)()
```

I would prefer

```
Dim barclass: Set barclass = new cls2.Init()
```

or

```
Dim oBar : Set oBar = new cls2.Init()
```

Comment: dang it! You're of course correct - the init requires brackets in order to execute, whilst class_initiliase is executed if present by the vbscript runtime. Silly me - Cheers :)